# Agregar key/value a todos los objetos anidados

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array de objetos, el cual tiene dentro un array de objetos (tambien tiene otro dentro).

```
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    prod: [
      {
        id: 1,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          },
          {
            id: 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    prod: [
      {
        id: 1,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          },
          {
            id: 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

La pregunta es como poder lograr ingresar en cada uno un key value nuevo para que quede así:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    isChecked: false,
    prod: [
      {
        id: 1,
        isChecked: false,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1,
            isChecked: false
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            isChecked: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        isChecked: false,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1,
            isChecked: false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isChecked: false,
    prod: [
      {
        id: 1,
        isChecked: false,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1,
            isChecked: false
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            isChecked: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        isChecked: false,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1,
            isChecked: false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

De momento he podido hacerlo en la primera capa

```js
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    prod: [
      {
        id: 1,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          },
          {
            id: 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    prod: [
      {
        id: 1,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          },
          {
            id: 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(array.map(object => {
  return {
    ...object,
    isChecked: false
  }
}));
```